# Laravel 5.6: What's the simplest way to set a variable using blade (without echoing it)?

Tags: php, laravel, variables, laravel-blade, laravel-5.6

So, i wish to set a variable which i will later append to the beginning of a resource's route, i'm currently using the following code:

```
{!! 
$baseDestinationImage=asset("img/uploads/destinations/");
!!}

<img src="{!! $baseDestinationImage.'/'.$destination->Dimage !!}" alt="{{$destination->Dname}}">
```

The above works fine, the only issue here is that the variable $baseDestinationImage also gets echoed, what's the simplest way to set a variable without it being displayed in Laravel 5.6?

Comment: use in controller then..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use in controller then..

```
public class YourController{ 
   ...
   public function index()
   {
        ...
        $baseDestinationImage=asset("img/uploads/destinations/");
        return view('your.blade.view', compact('baseDestinationImage'));
   }
}
```

in Blade

```
<img src="{{ $baseDestinationImage }}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't set variables in your Blade templates. Still, if you still want to do it, you can embed PHP code using the `@php` directive:

```
@php
    $baseDestinationImage=asset("img/uploads/destinations/");
@endphp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the [eloquent Accessors and mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators)
which allow you to format Eloquent attribute values when you retrieve or set them on model instances.

So your model should be like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class YourModel extends Model
{

    public function getPhotoAttribute($photo)
    {
        return $photo ? asset('your/path/' . $photo) : '';
    }

}
```

And on your blade you can use it like this:

```
{{ $object->photo }}
```